# What should I be careful when using the word "supervised" in paper writing?

Tags: terminology, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, hyperparameter, matrix-decomposition

I am a biologist using machine learning tool for my research. I modified matrix decomposition ($V \approx WH$) to fit my data and wanted to describe about that in my paper.

If I fixed one matrix factor ($W$), can I write the following sentences?

1. The dictionary ($W$) is supervised
2. This is a supervised method

I think 1. is correct because the dictionary is given/supervised. However, 2. is wrong because I do not aim to train the method with the labeled data. So, here is unsupervised learning but the dictionary is provided (as hyperparameter?).

What should I be careful when writing the word "supervised" in interdisciplinary research paper?

Answer (score 0):

"Supervised" usually means you have labeled response/target. I would say the matrix $W$ is "given" or "provided" or "fixed", rather than "supervised".

---

As a tool to recognize patterns or predict observations, machine learning models are "supervised" if they are given correct labels to try to predict. Compared to "unsupervised" models which try to recognize the patterns on their own. Supervised/unsupervised is the adjective that describes the model, not the (hyper)parameter. Hyperparameters are either searched for optimal values, or given based on empirical knowledge.